# Let user click on part to change the menu box? Flash ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, customization

To give you an idea of what type of Flash program I am making, here is a link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtE7LFAlkxU

As you can see in the video, when you click on a part of the shoe, the user is shown a menu for the color of that one part. I am making a t-shirt design program, so how could I make it so that when the user clicks one part, I can display a different box to customize that part?

EDIT:
So here is what I have done so far. As you can see, it is not very nice as it is just multiple color boxes with tint percentages. I would rather have the user be able to click on a part of the t-shirt and have the colorbox and the tint box pop up. I'm not too sure how to allow the user to do this.

```
import fl.motion.Color;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;

infoBox.text=String(slider.value)+"%";
var c:Color=new Color();
slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChanged);
picker.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, pickerChanged);
function sliderChanged(evt:SliderEvent):void {
    tintClip();
}

function pickerChanged(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    tintClip();
}

function tintClip():void {  
    var color:uint=picker.selectedColor;
    var val:Number=slider.value;
    c.setTint(color,val/100);
    clip1.transform.colorTransform=c;
    infoBox.text=String(val)+"%";
}

infoBox2.text=String(slider2.value)+"%";
var c2:Color=new Color();
slider2.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChanged2);
picker2.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, pickerChanged2);
function sliderChanged2(evt:SliderEvent):void {
    tintClip2();
}

function pickerChanged2(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    tintClip2();
}

function tintClip2():void { 
    var color2:uint=picker2.selectedColor;
    var val2:Number=slider2.value;
    c2.setTint(color2,val2/100);
    clip2.transform.colorTransform=c2;
    infoBox2.text=String(val2)+"%";
}

infoBox3.text=String(slider3.value)+"%";
var c3:Color=new Color();
slider3.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChanged3);
picker3.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, pickerChanged3);
function sliderChanged3(evt:SliderEvent):void {
    tintClip3();
}

function pickerChanged3(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    tintClip3();
}

function tintClip3():void { 
    var color3:uint=picker3.selectedColor;
    var val3:Number=slider3.value;
    c3.setTint(color3,val3/100);
    clip3.transform.colorTransform=c3;
    infoBox3.text=String(val3)+"%";
}

infoBox4.text=String(slider4.value)+"%";
var c4:Color=new Color();
slider4.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChanged4);
picker4.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, pickerChanged4);
function sliderChanged4(evt:SliderEvent):void {
    tintClip4();
}

function pickerChanged4(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    tintClip4();
}

function tintClip4():void { 
    var color4:uint=picker4.selectedColor;
    var val4:Number=slider4.value;
    c4.setTint(color4,val4/100);
    clip4.transform.colorTransform=c4;
    infoBox4.text=String(val4)+"%";
}

infoBox5.text=String(slider5.value)+"%";
var c5:Color=new Color();
slider5.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChanged5);
picker5.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, pickerChanged5);
function sliderChanged5(evt:SliderEvent):void {
    tintClip5();
}

function pickerChanged5(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    tintClip5();
}

function tintClip5():void { 
    var color5:uint=picker5.selectedColor;
    var val5:Number=slider5.value;
    c5.setTint(color5,val5/100);
    clip5.transform.colorTransform=c5;
    infoBox5.text=String(val5)+"%";
}

infoBox6.text=String(slider6.value)+"%";
var c6:Color=new Color();
slider6.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChanged6);
picker6.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, pickerChanged6);
function sliderChanged6(evt:SliderEvent):void {
    tintClip6();
}

function pickerChanged6(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    tintClip6();
}

function tintClip6():void { 
    var color6:uint=picker6.selectedColor;
    var val6:Number=slider6.value;
    c6.setTint(color6,val6/100);
    clip6.transform.colorTransform=c6;
    infoBox6.text=String(val6)+"%";
}

infoBox7.text=String(slider7.value)+"%";
var c7:Color=new Color();
slider7.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, sliderChanged7);
picker7.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, pickerChanged7);
function sliderChanged7(evt:SliderEvent):void {
    tintClip7();
}

function pickerChanged7(evt:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    tintClip7();
}

function tintClip7():void { 
    var color7:uint=picker7.selectedColor;
    var val7:Number=slider7.value;
    c7.setTint(color7,val7/100);
    clip7.transform.colorTransform=c7;
    infoBox7.text=String(val7)+"%";
}
```

Comment: I have, just asking a question for an answer, not trying to offend anyone. @JonnyHenly

Comment: Your question is too broad.  there are dozens of ways to accomplish this and any answer would be making too many assumptions.  Show your current code, what you've tried, and explain where you're getting stuck.

Comment: @JonnyHenly It's fine. I just edited it. Let me know if I should add more.

Comment: @LDMS Updated it. Let me know if you need more to answer.

Comment: Where is your issue do you already have a shirt, is the shirt divided in seperate parts ...sleaves , neck torso sprites ???

Comment: Yes I do. What I am looking to do is let the user click one part of the shirt, and the colorbox/tintbox appears, rather than having 7 of those boxes everywhere. Just like in the video above. @Careen

Comment: you can use them as a class or visibility = true or false on click

Comment: @Careen I tried that and it seemed OK, but let's say I want a button to swipe left or right (like this: <>) and if you click one of the buttons you get a menu shown above that changes the part of the t shirt I am editing. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You can use touch events? as3 adobe api!